# How to get all user reviews of an app at AppStore?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I want to get all the user reviews of an app from AppStore.

With this URL, I get the recent 500 reviews.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=447188370/xml

Is there a way to get all the reviews?

Comment: Are you using some RSS feed app?

Comment: nope. I am trying to get it by any means.